# How do I remove ntpd from the final image with my own recipe?

Tags: embedded, yocto, ntpd, bitbake

I want to get rid of all ntpd related stuff from my yocto linux image.

Currently I include the [meta-openembedded](https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded) layer, which is responsible that the NTP service [ntpd](https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/ntp/ntp_4.2.8p10.bb?h=pyro) is installed on my final image.

Since I don't need it and want to keep my image as small as possible, I would like to know how I can remove it with my own recipe without messing around with the meta-openembedded layer.

I tried to create a recipe recipes-support/ntp/ntp_%.bbappend recipe in which I set the follwing:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${BPN}:"

CONFIG_NTPD = "n"
```

But this does not seem to work. So my question would be how I can deactivate a recipe with another recipe or exclude it from the final image.

I have also tried it from a `python() {}` or `do_install:append()` block with `d.setVar("CONFIG_NTPD", "n")` but also without success. This would even have the charming advantage that I could link the removal of the NTP packets to another variable.